# Why union of sets does not work in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, set

I have a list of sets `[{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9', '1'}]`. I want to loop through this list and find the union of all of these sets. I have done the following but my set maintains empty:

```
my_set = set()
for i in [{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'}]:
  print(i)
  my_set.union(set(i))
  print(my_set)
print(my_set)
```

The output is the following:

```
{'1'}
set()
{'8', '2'}
set()
{'9', '3'}
set()
set()
```

**Note:**
Please fix my loop and do not propose a shortcut that does not use a loop and `union`.

Comment: The union functions returns a set, just do `my_set = my_set.union(set(i))`

Comment: what is the expected final result?

Comment: "Please fix my loop and do not propose a shortcut that does not use a loop and union": why?

Comment: `my_set.union(set(i))` does not work in-place, it returns a *new set*. You should use either `.update` for this or the augmented union operator: `myset |= i` (note, using `set(i)` is **pointless and inefficient**). You shouldn't do `my_set = my_set.union(i)` because this will be *inefficient in a loop*.

Comment: isn't this just `my_set = {a for s in [{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'}] for a in s}`?

Comment: try my_set=set()
for i in [{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'}]:
    my_set=my_set.union(i)
    
print(my_set)

Answer (score 4):

The `union` method returns a new set, but it doesn't change the current set(s). You need to (re)assign the result to `my_set`:

```
my_set = set()
for i in [{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'}]:
    my_set = my_set.union(i)
print(my_set)
```

Note that `i` is a set already, so no need to call `set(i)`

If you want an in-place change of `my_set`, use the following:

```
my_set = set()
for i in [{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'}]:
    my_set.update(i)
```

or

```
my_set = set()
for i in [{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'}]:
    my_set |= i
```

---

But `union()` accepts multiple sets as argument, so you can do the following (start with an empty set):

```
my_set = set().union({'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'})
```

No need for a loop.

You can also use `set.union(...)` as a class method (from balderman's comment below) instead of `set().union(...)`. And if your list (or tuple) of sets happens to be a variable, the following works:

```
sets = [{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'}]
my_set = set.union(*sets)
```

Comment: no need for creating `set` instance. `u = set.union({'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9', '1'})` is enough
`

Comment: @balderman Thanks, added. I hadn't come across the class method use mentioned in the documentation; it definitely makes sense though.

Answer (score 1):

Python's set method X.union(Y) returns a new set that is the union of X and Y. You're looking for `my_set.update(set(i))`.

You could, of course, write that as `my_set = my_set.union(set(i))`, but that's probably slower since it has different semantics (.update() uses the inplace addition method, while union will construct an additional copy.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reassign value returned by union

```
my_set = set()
for i in [{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9'}]:
  print(i)
  my_set = my_set.union(set(i))
  print(my_set)
print(my_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `my_set.update(i)` instead of union.  BTW you don't need the `set(i)` since `i` is already a set.  It would also work without casting to set if `i` was a list.

given that `i` is a set, you could also write it as:

```
my_set |= i
```

or even do it all in one line:

```
my_set = set().union(*[{'1'}, {'2','8'}, {'3','9', '1'}])
```